# How to add permission to the entire site from a list

Tags: list, permissions, person-or-group

I have a list "managers", this list have a name picker, this list will be used every time a new manager leaves or join. How can I give the people on this list permission to the entire site?

I mean, if I add someone on list "managers", it will automatically give this person the "owner" permission on the site.

Is this possible?

Regards,

Comment: You can create a SharePoint group and grant permission to that group.

Comment: Is there anyway to reference a list from that group? Or the other way around? Because I'm using the data from the list to fill an dropdown on another list. Is it possible to do this using the group as reference?

Answer (score 0):

The "perfered" method to accomplish this would be to either create a Managers SharePoint group and add / remove managers from that group, or create a Managers AD group, and assign permissions to that AD group and add / remove managers from the AD group.

Comment: Is there a way to reference a group from a third list? I have a list that contains a dropdown, and I get the names from the list 'managers' on that third list.

Comment: You could use a custom workflow to get the user from the list in SP then add the user to to correct SharePoint Group, but this would not account for when you need to remove a user.  If you are using SP onprem you might be able to get these 2010 workflow actions working in your environment.  You will want to use the "add user to group" action in your workflow.
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ilovesharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event receiver to update the users into owner group when add or update an item in the list.

[Sample to create the event receiver](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/)